# Contract gives erc20 tokens based on an event, to an empty wallet

Tags: wallets, mint

I have a new wallet address and no ETH.

I want to be able to request an amount of 10 erc-20 tokens. Because I do not have any eth on this wallet, I want to be able to get the tokens onto my wallet via this contract (maybe mint them - after approval?).

What is the best approact to get tokens to a virgin wallet? Sign the contract? 
Making any requests requires ether on my virgin wallet. At the expense of the contract holder, is it possible to initiate a transfer by the contract (in order to the contract to spend the tokens there?). What happens after the tokens are transferred? Can I retransfer them if i do not have any eth?

Is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: `via this contract` - what is "this contract"? Is it yours or someone else's? If it's yours, then you'll need a wallet with some ether in order to deploy it. Are you planning to mint tokens for this wallet or for some other wallet (the one without any ether)?

Answer (score 1):

You would need some ETH to sign a transaction. This is the normal way to go and it implies getting some ETH. You could, for example, buy some on an exchange.

The normal way isn't the only design pattern. In rare cases, a seller is willing to sign a transaction and send to you (instead of pulled in by you). That would be evident in their user interface, so if you don't see that, then it isn't offered.

A third way is to find a friend who has some ETH and will do it for you. They will receive the tokens and then they could forward them to your wallet. You'll have to buy them a beer for their trouble and the ETH they spent for you.

After you have tokens you won't be able to spend them until you have a little ETH. While it costs only pennies to do, it is more than zero and there is no way around this. So, your best bet is to purchase or trade for a little ETH in your wallet.

Hope it helps.